# Should I create 2 MX records or 2 A records on a Domain for one mail server

Tags: mx-record

I have a scenario:

one email server : mail.xyz.com

A Record : mail.xyz.com points to aaa.xxx.yyy.zzz (ISP1)

MX record : @ IN 10 mail.xyz.com

spf record : "v=spf1 mx a:mail.xyz.com ~all"

Now I want to add another IP from another ISP to point to same email server for failover scenario. What should I do? How would the records look like?

Both ISP's have PTR's pointing to : mail.xyz.com

Would appreciate your response.

### Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

Create a 2nd `MX` record & a 2nd `A` record, so that you have something like the following.

A - mail1.xyz.com - 192.168.1.1 (ISP 1)
A - mail2.xyz.com - 192.168.2.1 (ISP 2)

MX - 10 mail1.xyz.com
MX - 20 mail2.xyz.com

Update spf to include both `mail1` and `mail2`

You could just create an additonal `a` record for `mail.xyz.com` for the other isp IP address but without some kind of health check a dns server would still hand out either IP regardless of what one was working. `mx` records will be tried by the sending server in order.

Comment: Thanks. That make sense. 

Should I then have the second ISP change PTR to mail2.xyz.com ?